# C# Webbrowser Invoke Click Issue

Tags: c#, html

I Want to click this button on webbrowser using (invoke click)

```
<div class="ajax-load">
    <div id="yt0fake" style="display: none"></div>
    <input type="submit" class="gr-button add_request agree" id="59349129dd8aa" name="yt0" value="Something">                
</div>

webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("yt0").InvokeMember("click");
webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("yt0fake").InvokeMember("click");
```

Comment: Your HTML does not include a <form action=(URL) tag so no form will be submitted.  Your submit button does not have an onClick handler so that will not be called either.

Comment: is there anyway to click this button on a webbrowser programmatically of course

Comment: anyway to click it?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the button a **name** of "yt0" and then trying to find it by that **Id** instead.

```
<input type="submit" class="gr-button add_request agree" id="59349129dd8aa" name="yt0" value="Something">
```

You either need to change the Id from "59349129dd8aa" to "yt0" or use .GetElementByName

To keep the Id the way it is now try this:

```
 webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("59349129dd8aa").InvokeMember("Click");
```

Or fix the Id and use this

```
 webbrowser.Document.GetElementById("yt0").InvokeMember("Click");
```

Also notice it is Click not click.

Comment: the problem is ( id="59349129dd8aa" ) dosen't have a fix value it changes everytime i load the page so, is there anyway to get the id when the page is loaded?

Comment: Does the name stay yt0 or is that random too?